# É possível realizar um UPLOAD externo com ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

Tenho este código:

```
function uploadFile(x){


  //DEFINIÇÃO E RECEPÇÃO DAS VARIAVEIS PRA ENVIAR COM O AJAX
  var file              = document.getElementById("id_arq_documento_" + x ).files[0];
  var id                = document.getElementById("id_arq_" + x).value;
  var local_armazenado  = document.getElementById("local_armazenado_" + x).value;
  var autorizacao       = document.getElementById("autorizacao_" + x).value;

       //CHECA SE O INPUT FILE ESTÁ VAZIO...
        if(document.getElementById("id_arq_documento_" + x).files.length == 0){

            alert("Erro (" + x +"): Você deve selecionar um arquivo para envio");

        } else if(document.getElementById("local_armazenado_" + x ).value == 0){

            alert("Erro (" + x +"): Você deve informar o local de armazenamento");

        } else if( confirm('Deseja Realmente arquivar o documento? Esta ação não pode ser desfeita.')) {


        //SE O INPUT FILE NÃƒO ESTIVER VAZIO, EXECUTA A FUNÃ‡ÃƒO

          var formdata = new FormData();
          formdata.append("arqUP", file);
          formdata.append("autorz", autorizacao);

          var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
          ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
          ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
          ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
          ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
          ajax.open("POST", "https://www.meusite.com.br/upload/upload.php?");
          ajax.send(formdata);

          //POR SEGURANÃ‡A, QUANDO A FUNÃ‡ÃƒO FOR ACIONADA, IRÃ DESABILITAR O CAMPO processar E CHECKBOX
            document.getElementById("botao_processar_"+ x ).disabled = 'true';
            document.getElementById("progressBar_"+ x).style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("botao_processar_"+ x).style.display = 'none';


          function progressHandler(event){
          var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
          document.getElementById("progressBar_"+ x).value = Math.round(percent);

          document.getElementById("status_"+ x).innerHTML = "Processando: " +Math.round(percent)+"%";


        }
        function completeHandler(event){

          document.getElementById("status_" + x).innerHTML = event.target.responseText;
          document.getElementById("progressBar_" + x).value = 0;

          document.getElementById("progressBar_" + x).remove();
          document.getElementById("botao_processar_" + x).remove();
          document.getElementById("id_arq_documento_" + x).disabled = 'true';
          document.getElementById("local_armazenado_" + x).disabled = 'true';
          document.getElementById("status_arquivo_" + x).innerHTML= '';
          alert('Up ok' + x);



        }
        function errorHandler(event){
          document.getElementById("status_" + x).innerHTML = "Falha ao enviar";
        }
        function abortHandler(event){
          document.getElementById("status_" + x).innerHTML = "Envio abortado";
        }

      }
    }
```

Quando chamo a função dentro do meu servidor, ele executa normalmente:

```
ajax.open("POST", "upload.php");
```

Mas quando tento enviar o POST para uma URL externa:

```
ajax.open("POST", "https://www.meusite.com.br/upload/upload.php?");
```

Ele me retorna o erro:

> Falha ao enviar

E no meu console do Inpecionar Elemento aparece:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://10.4.0.218' is therefore not allowed access.

Já verifiquei tudo. Permissões de escrita no servidor remoto, tudo.

O que pode ser? Tens alguma ideia?

Comment: E esse arquivo externo seria exatamente o mesmo código PHP que você roda localmente?

Comment: Na verdade ele é uma API a qual tenho que informar as seguintes variáveis: $arqUP que é o arquivo para UPLOAD e autorz que é a autorização de upload:

Comment: E essa API permite requisições externas?

Comment: Sim. Abri meu console do Inspecionar Elemento e apareceu o seguinte erro:  Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://10.4.0.218' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: O local onde vai chamar o arquivo de upload vai ser em outro domínio mesmo?

Comment: Sim Sim. Já inserir o header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.merusite.com.br');  e nada!

Comment: Adicionou header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *") no arquivo upload.php?

Comment: Sim. Foi adicionado, mas mesmo assim persiste!

Comment: @netoweb Você precisa adicionar ao `header` o valor do endereço que fará a requisição. Dado a mensagem de erro, diria que o IP de onde está fazendo a requisição é 10.4.0.218, então é esse valor que precisa adicionar ao `header`. Por exemplo: `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: 10.4.0.218")`

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss - No caso essa linha iria na minha própria aplicação ou na API?

Comment: Na API que receberá a requisição

Comment: Eu sei que isso é uma gambiarra. Fiz por testes. Adicionei esta extensão ao chrome e funcionou perfeitamente. https://goo.gl/hEoirz